# Tail-recursive program in prolog which counts positive and negative numbers

Tags: prolog, tail-recursion

I want to write a tail-recursive program in prolog: `count_neg(Ls, N, R)` which is true if `Ls` is a list of integers and `N` is the amount of negative elements. `R` should represent the list of non-negative elements.

An example:

```
count_neg([1,-2,0,1,2,-3],N,R).
N = 2,
R = 4.
```

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
count_neg(Ls, N, R) :- count_neg(Ls, 0, 0, N, R).
count_neg([L|Ls], Cnt1, Cnt2, N, R) :- (L > 0 -> C1 is Cnt1 + 1, !; L < 0 -> C2 is Cnt2 + 1, !), count_neg(Ls, C1, C2, N, R).

count_neg([], Cnt1, Cnt2, N, R) :- N is Cnt1.
count_neg([], Cnt1, Cnt2, N, R) :- R is Cnt2.
```

The problem is, that `N` and `R` both are initialized with 0 at the beginning which is correct, but when the program should count the first negative number it does not start counting from zero but from _21532 and results with an error:

[image]

Has anyone an idea what's wrong here? I also want to use Cuts in my program.

Comment: Why all the cuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact you don't update correctly the indices and call the predicate `is/2` with arguments not instantiated.
A possible solution could be:

```
count_neg(Ls, N, R):- 
    count_neg(Ls, 0, 0, N, R).

count_neg([],C1,C2,C1,C2).
count_neg([L|Ls], Cnt1, Cnt2, N, R):- 
    (L > 0 -> 
        C1 is Cnt1 + 1,
        C2 is Cnt2
    ;
        C2 is Cnt2 + 1,
        C1 is Cnt1), 
    count_neg(Ls, C1, C2, N, R).

?- count_neg([1,-2,0,1,2,-3,8],N,R).
N = 4
R = 3
```

Also you don't need the last two predicates and the cuts. In the question you say that `R` should represent a list but with the previous solution you don't get a list. To obtain it, you can modify the program like this:

```
countNeg(L,N,R):-
    countNeg(L,N,0,R,[]).

countNeg([],N,N,R,R).
countNeg([H|T],N,C,R,L1):-
    (   H < 0 ->  
        C1 is C+1,
        countNeg(T,N,C1,R,L1);
    append(L1,[H],L2),
    countNeg(T,N,C,R,L2)).

?- countNeg([1,-2,0,1,2,-3],N,R).
N = 2
R = [1, 0, 1, 2]
```

In this solution you can also notice that you call `countNeg/5` in each branch (and i check if `< 0`, while in the previous case you check `> 0`).